# Adding a toolbar to a preferencescreen fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-preferences

I'm trying to use the Android Jetpack [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) guide with a toolbar. The guide says that the root tag to be <PreferencesScreen>, so I can not include the toolbar in the xml. I'm using a **NoActionBar** theme. According to the Android Jetpack [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations) for support app bar variations it is advised to remove the top bar from the activity and instead define it in each destination fragment. So I have the following files:

**preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="notifications"
        app:title="Enable message notifications" />

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"
        app:title="Send feedback" />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingsFragment.kt**

```
class SettingsFragment: PreferenceFragmentCompat(){
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine, and the settingsFragments opens well, but because I do use the NoActionBar theme it seems like there is not way for me to add the toolbar without defining it in the main_activity. Is my assessment correct, or is there a way for me to add a custom toolbar afterall to the preference fragment?

Comment: Try a SettingsActivity and inside onCreate replace it with the fragment. That's how I would've done it in java. Not familiar with kt though!

Comment: That is the issue, I do not want to make a global toolbar (in the activity). According to their guide it should be possible to implement a toolbar for each fragment. That is why I am posting this question on here. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe it's too late but you can achieve it in this way ->

- define preference theme:

```xml
<style name="PrefsTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/fragment_settings</item>
</style>
```

- fragment_settings.xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/item_toolbar" />

<!-- the id is defined by the support lib. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:targetApi="n" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- set it in your app theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PrefsTheme</item>
</style>
```

Then in your SettingsFragment you can find toolbar by id and make all customizations to it:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)?.let {
        // Customize toolbar 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Other option for this problem. In Preference Screen, u can use Preference Categoy, with layout atribute.

A piece of code that I'm talking about:

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Prueba"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout="@layout/activity_titulo"

        />
```

Code of activity_titulo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".activities.NuevoParteActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_cabecera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GVenaPDA.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settings_general"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/cabecera_info"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val root = ((listView.parent as FrameLayout).parent as LinearLayout)
    val toolbar = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.toolbar, root, false) as MaterialToolbar
    toolbar.title = getText(R.string.title_settings)
    root.addView(toolbar, 0)
}

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}}
```

You add a toolbar view dynamically after preferences.xml is inflated. I tried @Yerón Barreiro Martínez's solution. However, I can not reach the toolbar instance on the fragment page. So I can not set the title or click listener.